# Add Custom Block Supports to Core Block

Tags: block-editor

I'm wondering if there's a way to add a custom block support (possibly the wrong terminology) to a core block. I understand that it's possible to turn existing block supports off and on and also to add custom block styles via PHP and theme.json but would really like to leverage a number entry for a custom use.

Specifically, I'd like to add a 'translateY' value entry to the image block. Something like in the attached image. I've already added 'Translate Up' and 'Translate Down' custom styles which `transform:translate(Y):-50%` and `transform:translate(Y):50%` respectively but the designs that I've now been provided with now require more flexibility, ideally sliding to choose a percent value between -100 and 100.

[image: Translate Y Block Style]

Is this possible currently and what should I be Googling? Thanks.

Comment: you'd need to filter things in both JS and PHP, filtering the edit component to wrap it in something that has an additional inspector control to add the UI, a filter in PHP to add the new attribute, a filter in PHP to modify the output to include the css styling. I don't have the specifics at hand to write an answer though. I would suggest avoid allowing arbitrary number entry, and instead confine it to set increments and values.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom J Nowell. Sounds like a lot, I've come up with a custom style option for the time being but will dig into this route when I have some time.